# Angular 2 RouteConfig

Tags: angular

I would like create RouteConfig dynamically like this

```
for (let route of routes) {

  { path: route.name , component: route.component }

}
```

Not like this:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'Info' , component: InfoComponent },
{ path: 'About' , component: AboutComponent },
```

Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

You answer your question already. Route in angular is just Array of object. so you can create variable and push object(which it's Route interface) to the variable. and pass the variable to `RouteModule.forChild()` or `forRoot()` method.

```
const coreRoutes:Routes = (function(){
  let result_routes = [];
  for (let route of routes) {
    result_routes.push({ path: route.name , component: route.component });  
  } 
  return result_routes;
 })();


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(coreRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers:[]
})
```

In the example above I use self invoking function for make variable not visble to global.It's not necessary but it's good to do for prevent name collision.